# JTable, new row doesn't get inserted with table->save method

Tags: component, custom-component, database, jtable

I'm trying to insert a row with the `table->save()` method, but the method executes an UPDATE instead. There is no row available, so it needs to be inserted. Does anyone know how to get it inserted?

My code:

```
$tableLocation = $this->getTable("Location", 'Table', array());
if (!$tableLocation->save($data))
{
    $this->setError($user->getError());
    return false;
}
```

This runs the query UPDATE, but it needs to be INSERT if not available.

EDIT: Ok so I found the solution, partly. My construct method in my Table class:

```
parent::__construct('#__matches_location', 'user_id', $db);
```

Because I set the primary key to the user_id field it tried to update. So I changed it to this:

```
parent::__construct('#__matches_location', 'id', $db);
```

But now I get another issue:

```
Duplicate entry '185' for key 'user_id'
```

This is correct, there is a record for 185 in it already.

The correct way is to use the id as primary key, but then I need to change the Location table store (?) method to set everything right. Is that correct?

Ok so I tried the following:

```
public function bind($array, $ignore = '')
    {

        if($this->load(['user_id' => $array['user_id']])) {
            $array['id'] = $this->id;
        }

        //echo $this->id;

        return parent::bind($array, $ignore);
    }
```

This gives me an memory error. Probably a memory leak somewhere. So I moved the code to the store fucntion:

```
public function store($updateNulls = false)
    {

        if($this->load(['user_id' => $this->user_id])) {
            $this->id = $this->id;
        }

        return parent::store($updateNulls);
    }
```

But this doesn't do anything, because well, I load the row, and thus the new values sent are being overwritten. Do I need to get these values first and then change them in the new loaded row?

It all seems so cumbersome, there must be an easier way right? I cannot imagine this is some sort of unique situation.

SOLUTION:

```
//Store data, check if records exist 
if($tableLocation->load(['user_id' => $data['user_id']])) { $data['id'] = $tableLocation->id; } 

if (!$tableLocation->save($data)) 
{ 
     $this->setError($user->getError()); 
     return false;
```

}

Comment: According to https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class, you don't need to bother passing in `'Table'` or `array()` -- these are default parameters.  This advice will not resolve your question, but it does mean that you can simplify your call to `$this->getTable("Location")`.  Your question is missing some vital details.  What does `$data` contain? You say that a row is being updated -- is only one row updated or multiple? How are the updated rows targeted? What is the rendered executed query?

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Please never add a "solution" section to a question.  If you have a unique way to resolve the page, please add a new answer and remove the solution from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[save()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4d1fee713dae4258b93123b83aba9020cfee6253/libraries/src/Table/Table.php#L917) calls [store()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4d1fee713dae4258b93123b83aba9020cfee6253/libraries/src/Table/Table.php#L776).

Store() works like this:
If a primary key value is set the row with that primary key value will be updated with the instance property values. If no primary key value is set a new row will be inserted into the database with the properties from the Table instance.

Please check, if the primary key of the database table is set in your $data objekt.

Comment: Yes, the primary key (see my above answer) was set. I changed it to the initial primary key "id". Now I get another error (duplicate key user_id) which is also correct because I made user_id unique. I probably have to change the store() or check() method to check if the user_id is already available, and if so get the primary key and add that to the database?

Comment: Found the solution, moved it into my model, instead of trying to make it work in my Table class:

 //Store data, check if records exist
     if($tableLocation->load(['user_id' => $data['user_id']])) {
   $data['id'] = $tableLocation->id;
  }

     if (!$tableLocation->save($data))
     {
         $this->setError($user->getError());
         return false;
     }